# MBProgressHUD not show

Tags: ios, dispatch, mbprogresshud

When I write like this, it works as expected:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   MBProgressHUD.showAdded(to: navigationController!.view, animated: true)
}
```

However, when I put it in DispatchQueue.main block, the hud doesn't show:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

   DispatchQueue.main.async {
      MBProgressHUD.showAdded(to: self.navigationController!.view, animated: true)
   }
}
```

I debug the view hierarchy, and there is a layout issue:

"Position and size are ambiguous for MBProgressHUD"

The navigationController is a childViewController of fatherViewController and the container view is set by auto layout in fatherViewController's view.

Is that cause the issue?

Comment: you can write `self.view` instead of `self.navigationController!.view`
 or 
do you have your `UINavigationCotroller` added in storyboard if you have than make it as initialViewController connect as RootViewControlller  than than Try adding `self.navigationController!.view`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have built a demo to test it, but it didn't occur. So I rechecked my code and found I put some work in `DispatchQueue.main.async` which block the UI and cause the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I performed test especially for you and following code works for me:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

   DispatchQueue.main.async {
      MBProgressHUD.showAdded(to: self.navigationController!.view, animated: true)
   }
}
```

so the problem is somewhere else located

Comment: I have updated the question. The navigationController is a childViewController and it's container view is set by auto layout. I think maybe this cause the issue.

Answer (score 2):

The root UIView geometry is **not being calculated**(`viewDidLayoutSubviews` is not called) at the point of `viewDidLoad`. I'd recommend putting your code into `viewDidAppear`. 
Also, no need to explicitly call it inside `DispatchAsync.main`, as other mentioned it is being called in the UI thread unless you want to call it from the background thread.

Answer (score 0):

Actually MBProgressHUD works on UI main thread and you are trying to call it in background thread.

Try this:-

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       DispatchQueue.main.async {  start()
 }
}
func start(){


  MBProgressHUD.showAdded(to: self.navigationController!.view, animated: true)}
```

Comment: He is dispatching it to the main thread instead of background.